# Save multiple sheets to different workbooks and attach these to outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need a macro to do the following job:

I have a workbook with 6 sheets. Each with a different name. Sheets names are ENT, GHD, T3 etc.

I want to copy the contents of each sheet and save it into a different workbook with different names along with the date n time stamp.

For example Sheet ENT  must be saved as XYZ Report  DATE TIME. Xlsx and this file needs to be attached to outlook.

Similarly for GHD the file name should be ABC Report DATE TIME. Xlsx.
And similarly for the T3 sheet and the rest 3 sheets. All these files are to be mailed to different people.

The catch being these new files must get saved to the folder of the original file from which it was created.

Comment: We need the code showing what you've tried so far in order to help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get a better response if you demonstrate a modicum of effort on your own, first. Copying sheets to a new workbook is fairly simple. Emailing a single sheet as an attachment is definitely supported and also not very difficult. Saving to a known/specified directory is beginner stuff.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to loop through the worksheets like the below:

```
for Each xSheet In activeworkbook.worksheets
```

then call the saveas method using the worksheet name and workbook path

```
xsheet.saveas activeworkbook.path & xSheet.Name & " Report " & vba.forma(now, "dd mmm yyyy hhmmss"), xlnormal
```

then you want to get create an Outlook mail item, set the recipient, subject, and attachment, then send it...

so that should get you started, then you just add the Reference to Outlook Application in the References to enable you to use the objects...

HTH

Philip

Comment: Philip and @Sam need ur help guys

Comment: whose help do I need, and why?

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub COMEON()
  Dim onePublishObject As PublishObject
  Dim oneSheet As Worksheet
  Dim scriptingObject As Object
  Dim outlookApplication As Object
  Dim outlookMail As Object
  Dim htmlBody As String
  Dim htmlFile As String
  Dim textStream, fil As String
  Dim dummy As Workbook


  Today = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy")

  Set dummy = ActiveWorkbook
  Set scriptingObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set outlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  For Each oneSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets




                                                        Dim StrBody As String
                                                        StrBody = " THIS IS A TEST" & " " & UCase(oneSheet.Name) & " " & "XYZ," & vbNewLine & _
                                                        vbNewLine & _
                                                        "Please FIND ATTACHED <B>'XYZ REPORT'<B>"





    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(oneSheet.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dummy.Path & "\" & oneSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set outlookMail = outlookApplication.CreateItem(0)
    With outlookMail
        .htmlBody = StrBody & htmlBody
        .attachments.Add dummy.Path & "\" & oneSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
        .Display
        .Subject = "XYZ Report" & " " & UCase(oneSheet.Name) & " " & "(" & Today & ")"

    End With
  Next oneSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: In the above code  1.I cant quite figure out how to give individual names to each of my sheets. 2. Write a different mail for each different sheet and send it to different persons. 3. I want to attach only 5 sheets out of the 7 my template (so that would mean 5 different mails)

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Its just that In the above code 1.I cant quite figure out how to give individual names to each of my sheets. 2. Write a different mail for each different sheet and send it to different persons. 3. I want to attach only 5 sheets out of the 7 my template (so that would mean 5 different mails)